# link_to in Rails to AngularJS equivalent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, angularjs

Code in html.haml in Rails using AngularJS

```
%table
  %tbody{:"ng-init" => "my_model=#{@current_user_things.to_json}"}
    %tr{:"ng-repeat" => "row in my_model"}
      %td
        %a{:href => "{{row.permalink}}"}
          {{row.name}}
```

I am trying to replace what was originally a link_to in Rails that linked to row's page to it's equivalent using AngularJS. As I am providing AngularJS a template to repeat with, I now need to generate the link on the client side. Is there a way to do that easily?

I realise I can simply go `%a{:href => "http://blah.com/rows/{{row.permalink}}"}` but I would prefer a more elegant solution as the host can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I could fix it like this:

```
%a{:href => "#{url_for(:action => 'index')}/{{row.permalink}}"}
```